# Cracks in bricks, needs foundation work or can it be watched?

Tags: foundation, brick, cracks

This house belongs to my mother who is in her 70's. She already needs a new roof and is saving for that. 
As of now she can not really afford to fix foundation so I need honest opinions. Is this something that needs addressed NOW, or can it be monitored and if stays stabled addressed later on.

The cracks are on exterior only. There is no cracks in walls on the inside. Only one window is hard to open. Others work well. Doors work well. We feel no slanting in floors. The house is in Ohio (not sure if that matters)

Honestly have NO idea how long the ones on the side and back have been there.

Front of the house. This is under a bay window. This crack has been there for a long time (years) but never took pictures to compare. 
https://i.imgur.com/GKns4Nq.jpg
https://i.imgur.com/e888ulR.jpg

Side of the house, bedroom A 
https://i.imgur.com/UUJiTZq.jpg

Back of the house also bedroom A (also under only window that is hard to open, the window is old and never used so we don't know if being hard to open is a new problem)
https://i.imgur.com/rc2gnYf.jpg
https://i.imgur.com/eGmZTPQ.jpg

Back of the house Bedroom B
https://i.imgur.com/jJTgYJm.jpg
https://i.imgur.com/KSXxSv1.jpg

Over the garage, this crack is by far worst and has been there for many years. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7Fdq.jpg

Comment: What kind of foundation is it? Basement, slab, etc? And if there is a basement or crawlspace, are there cracks in the walls there too?

Comment: Its a crawlspace. Neither me and my mom can go in there to check. Last time it was checked small cracks were noted (I think 2 the one by bay window and back of the house).

Comment: How old is the house?

Comment: It was built in 1972

Comment: May I ask what the professionals, that looked at the cracks, said needs to be done?

Comment: We did not call anyone yet. My mom is already freaking out about needing a roof, she is on social security. I wanted to come here and ask some advice first, so I can prepare her.

Comment: if you don't care about selling the house, letting it go should be ok for several more years if it's not getting worse. If you do need the money from the sale of the house, you will likely have to fix it anyway, in which case it would be better to spend the money fixing it sooner for peace of mind.